# coordinate geometry - find point in right-angled triangle

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm making a map.  I've come across a geometry problem, and I'm not so knowledgeable about maths! Let me illustrate with pictures.  I am trying to plot flightpaths with a curved line, using a quadratic bezier curve as outlined here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves

So I need to calculate 1 control point, like this (red point):

[image]

I have already managed to calculate the midpoint of the line, and also the correct angle to project the control point perpendicular to the line.  But how do I proceed from here?  The problem can be boiled down as follows:

[image]

What are the coordinates of the red point? (I know the length of the hypotenuse as I define this elsewhere).

I'm sorry, I'm sure this is very basic geometry but I am unsure of the terms to search for and hence, haven't found anything on Google.  I am working with GPS coordinates which are in decimal format, and can be negative.  Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-side-right-triangle.html).

Comment: A quadratic Bezier curve does not pass through its control point.

Comment: Yes you are right that is a little misleading.  This diagram is more accurate: http://www.ams.org/featurecolumn/images/november2008/quad-halving.gif

Comment: In the end this answer in Javascript solved my problem using a far more elegant technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553811

Answer (score 1):

if $(a,b)$ is the cordinates of the known point. then unknown point is $(a+r\cos \theta,b+r\sin \theta)$ where $r$ is the known length and $\theta$ the angle.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I am sure your answer is correct, but I've been struggling for a while to get the right results (it could be a number of different things outside the scope of this question). Can I please ask - aside from comparing each latitude and longitude to zero, do you know of a more elegant way to get this solution to work with negative coordinates?